# Visual Studio - Xaml expandindo sozinho

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, formatação, xaml

Visual Studio 2019.

Quando digito "<" para incluir um novo componente, todas tags abaixo estão se expandindo, provavelmente por gerar erro de tag não fechada, como solucionar esse problema pro meu código não ficar sempre se expandindo sozinho ?

[image: Exeplo]

Comment: e se fechar a tag não fica certo?

Comment: Os erros somem, como esperado. mas as tags continuam abertas, isso atrapalha e muito na legibilidade de código em paginas bem populadas